# Map an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Is there a method in lodash to map over an array of arrays

I would like to do something like this so that it keeps the structure of the array.

```
def double(x) { return x*2 }

_([[1,2],[3,4]]).somemethod(double) == [[2,4],[6,8]]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make your code much cleaner with ES2015 arrow functions:

```
var array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
var double = x => x * 2;
var doubledArray = _.map( array, subarray => _.map( subarray, double ));
```

Using vanilla JS:

```
var array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
var double = x => x * 2;
var doubledArray = array.map( subarray => subarray.map( double ));
```

Comment: Assuming the target environment supports them and/or they transpile it with something like Babel.

Comment: arrow functions have nothing to do with his question.

Answer (score 46):

Just [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) it twice:

```
var array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
var doubledArray = _.map(array, function (nested) {
    return _.map(nested, function (element) {
        return element * 2;
    });
});
```

Or without [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/):

```
var doubledArray = array.map(function (nested) {
    return nested.map(function (element) {
        return element * 2;
    });
});
```

Furthermore, consider using [es6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var doubledArray = array.map(nested => nested.map(element => element * 2));
```

Answer (score 9):

It's much more elegant to use the **es6** [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) within your map statement:

```
array.map(([ a, b ]) => [ a*2, b*2 ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const deepMap=(input,callback)=>input.map(entry=>entry.map?deepMap(entry,callback):callback(entry))

//test 

deepMap([1,2,3,[1,2]],x=>x*2) // [1,4,9,[1,4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to do that at ES5:

```
[].concat(...this.array1.map(ap => ap.subArray))
```

Comment: I'm failing to see how this answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

It can be a kind of entangle:

```
var Coef = Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map(function(){return
Array.apply(null, Array(4)).map(function(){return 0})})
```

Nevertheless, it can be useful if you want to initialize an array in *Gas*