# Map an array to create a new array of pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two separate arrays and I'm trying to create a new nested array that has values grouped together.

Can I use the map() method and pair each item inside the map method?

There is a similar question here: [Map an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325767/map-an-array-of-arrays)

However, he context is different because I don't have a nested array to begin with.

```
   var letters = [a, b, c];
   var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

   var lettersAndNumbers = letters.map((letter) => {
       numbers.forEach((number) => {
          return letter, number;
       );
    });
    
    // lettersAndNumbers = [[a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 3]]
```

Thank you for any tips, hints, or solutions!

Comment: Note that a callback return does not return to the outer function

Comment: `[a, b, c]`, you mean... `["a", "b", "c"]`

Answer (score 3):

To do this, use the following

```
var letters = ['a','b','c'];
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var letterAndNumbers = letters.map((letter,index) => {
       return [letter,numbers[index]];
})
```

And if you print it, you will receive the following output

```
console.log(letterAndNumbers)
[ [ 'a', 1 ], [ 'b', 2 ], [ 'c', 3 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is `Index`. Make use of it for retrieve a `numbers[i]` by that iterating index:

```js
const letters = ["a", "b", "c"];
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

const lettersAndNumbers = letters.map((a, i) => [a, numbers[i]]);


console.log(lettersAndNumbers)
// lettersAndNumbers = [[a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map but here is a reduce just for the sake of it.

```js
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

var lettersAndNumbers = (letters, numbers) => letters.reduce((results, letter, index) => {
  results.push([letter, numbers[index]]);
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(lettersAndNumbers(letters, numbers));
```