# How can I map a nested array in JS

Tags: javascript

Here is my array:

```
const main = [
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369']],
];
```

and here is my function:

```
const convertor = (x) => {
  const splitted = x.split(':');
  console.log(splitted);
  const converted = splitted[0] * 60 + splitted[1] * 60 + splitted[2];
  return converted;
};
```

I want to map this function on each nested array

I tried this but I got an error:

```
const resu = main.map((x) => {
  x.map((y) => {
    convertor(y);
  });
});
```

x.split is not a function

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325767/map-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski expected output should be timestamps converted to seconds. for example : 02:50:20,656 turns into : 312020,656

Comment: @moemous Got the answer `132021,369`, please check my code?

Comment: The `.map()` callback has to return the new value. Your callbacks don't return anything.

Comment: _"x.split is not a function"_ - `x` is an array and not a string.

Comment: @Andreas yes thats my problem! what should I do then?

Comment: It's an array with one element... -> `x[0]` o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some mistakes:

1. Expression `(x) => { /* a few lines of code */ }` requires the use of the `return`  keyword to return the result, while `(x) => /* single line of code */` doesn't.
2. Your array `main` is three-dimensional array, not two-dimensional.

Try this:

```
const resu = main.map((x) => {
  return x.map((y) => {
    return y.map(convertor);
  });
});
```

Or easier:

```
const resu = main.map(
    (x) => x.map(
        (y) => y.map(convertor)
    )
);
```

```js
const main = [
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369']],
];

const convertor = (x) => {
  const splitted = x.split(':');
  const converted = splitted[0] * 60 + splitted[1] * 60 + splitted[2];
  return converted;
};

const resu = main.map(
    (x) => x.map(
        (y) => y.map(convertor)
    )
);

console.log(resu);
```

Comment: _"while (x) => /* single line of code */ doesn't"_ - That's not a matter of single line or not. `{ }` creates a block. And that's what triggers the need of an explicit `return`. This is also the reason why you have to wrap an object in `( )` without an explicit `return`: (foo) => `({ bar: foo })`

Answer (score 1):

**Issues**

1. Note that there are 3 level nested arrays, so there should be 3 `maps()`
2. `return` is required if you use `{}` in the arrow function

```js
const main = [
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369']],
];

const convertor = (x) => {
  const splitted = x.split(':');
  const converted = splitted[0] * 60 + splitted[1] * 60 + splitted[2];
  return converted;
};

const resu = main.map((x) => {
  return x.map((y) => {
    return y.map((z) => {
      return convertor(z);
    });
  });
});

console.log(resu);
```

**Shorter version**

```
main.map(x => x.map(y => y.map(convertor)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const main = [
  [
    ['02:20:21,369'],
    ['02:20:21,369'],
    ['02:20:21,369'],
    ['02:20:21,369']
  ],
  [
    ['02:20:21,369'],
    ['02:20:21,369']
  ],
  [
    ['02:20:21,369'],
    ['02:20:21,369'],
    ['02:20:21,369']
  ],
  [
    ['02:20:21,369']
  ],
];


const convertor = (x) => {
  const splitted = x.split(':');
  //console.log(splitted);
  const converted = splitted[0] * 60 + splitted[1] * 60 + splitted[2];
  return converted;
};

const mappedMain = main.map(i => {
 return i.map(j => {
  return convertor(...j)
 })
})

//Or
//const mappedMain = main.map(i => i.map(j => convertor(...j)))



console.log(mappedMain);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to recursively go through the array(s). This way you are not limited to a specific depth level.

```js
const main = [
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369'], ['02:20:21,369']],
  [['02:20:21,369']],
];

const convertor = (x) => {
  const splitted = x.split(':');
  // console.log(splitted);
  const converted = splitted[0] * 60 + splitted[1] * 60 + splitted[2];
  return converted;
};

const convertTimeToSec = (arr) => {
  for(let i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
    if(Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      arr[i] = convertTimeToSec(arr[i]);
    }else{
      arr[i] = convertor(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(convertTimeToSec(main));
```